# How to set HTML element's margin using percent of page height?

Tags: css, height

I have a div that I want to position at 10% below the beginning of the page. If I use this CSS rule:

```
#div-block{
   margin-top: 10%;
}
```

The div's computed margin-top is approximately 192px (my screen resolution is 1920 x 1080) so all browsers I tested are using the page's width (rather than height) for calculating the value.

How can I do to make them calculate using the height (suppose 1080px) using only CSS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the width to calculate the percentage is correct behavior.  You cannot set a margin based on a percentage of the height.

One possibility is to set `position: absolute; top 10%` on the element, or use JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/g8Re6/

Comment: .. not to mention that using `top` is natural way to set the top position.

Comment: Thanks for answering. And do you know some way to change that behavior?

Comment: @NicoRodsevich You mean this behavior? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

Comment: Yeah, that one... Thanks for the link, @ExplosionPills
Enough of this, will use top from now on :/

Answer (score 3):

The percentage is taken from the element that the `div` is wrapped in. You can instead use javascript or jQuery to set the height of the div in proportion to the page height.

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport

$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

So you would do

```
var documentHeight = $(document).height();
var percentageHeight = documentHeight * .1;

$("#div-block").height(percentageHeight );
```

Comment: Tanks that works, but I'm wondering if there is a CSS-only way for doing this

Comment: Not without setting absolute positioning - which I despise personally :)

Comment: Yeah, I despise it too, but well, I'vs just changed my mind, that's the correct way of doing this, so...